# IPP Customer Query Issue - SyncManager updates timestamp even though no changes made

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is there a workaround for this case?

1. I programmatically modify a customer in the cloud.
2. SyncManager pulls that customer down to QuickBooks.
3. I subsequently query for modified customers and get that same customer back since SyncManager updates the timestamp even though no real changes occurred in QuickBooks.

I need a StartCreatedTMS equivalent for list items so that I will only pull entities that were physically modified in QuickBooks.

I've attempted to insert the StartCreatedTMS tag into the query but they are ignored, ostensibly because they were designed for transactions.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by no real change happened in QuicKBooks. If you modified the record in the cloud, then it synced and modified the record in QuicKBooks...hence a change, Same if another application modified the record. Alternatively you can look at the company meta data for last date a sync ran

Comment: My use case is a sync app.  After I programmatically modify three customers in the cloud, my app and - for all intent and purposes - QuickBooks - are in sync.  What's occurring though, is that when SyncManager runs those three customers get pushed down to QuickBooks and update the local QuickBooks record to perform the changes that my app initiated and already accounted for.  

So when I make another call to pull modified customers, those three customers are getting sent back my way and the only 'change' from my standpoint is the modified date.

Comment: I was hoping there was something like StartCreatedTMS that might allow me to (somewhat) mitigate this situation by querying only by modifications that occurred in QuickBooks (not data services).

Comment: I disagree with the statement that when you modify a record in the cloud that QuickBooks is in sync. If the customer does not run sync, turns off their laptop, or there is an error syncing the record then they are not in sync. However if you look here: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Company you can get last upload (to the cloud) and last write back (to the desktop) time for the company file

Comment: Ok.  I'll figure out a solution based on last upload / last write solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give this thread an answer, you can use the Last Upload Time and Last Write Back time for the company file. http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Company

Thanks 
Jarred